# WordPress Gallery Displays Code

Tags: wordpress

I inserted a gallery into a post of mine on WordPress but when I view the gallery on the website it comes up like this:

```
     [gallery size="medium" ids="110,109,108"]
```

I've made the post go to a certain page of the website in the code:

```
    <?php
     $post_id = 5;
     $queried_post = get_post($post_id);
     echo $queried_post->post_content; 
     ?>
```

could this affect it?Why does this happen? How can I fix this?
(I've also discovered for any shortcodes it does the same thing)
Thanks

Comment: its because you are not using the loop, within the loop there is code to look for shortcodes and call the relevant function so if you just query the post content, you get text

Comment: How do I do use the loop, but only fetch a specific post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you can use the Wordpress Loop as they are in default or another way is you have to use like `add_filter('the_content', $queried_post->post_content);`. Thanks!